# Как избавиться нескольких срабатываний скрипта при залипании клавиши Enter?

Tags: javascript

Заметил в логах и перепроверил на своей клавиатуре, что при вводе в текстовое поле искомого значения и нажатия клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd> происходит как-бы залипание клавиши клавиатуры и PHP-скрипт отрабатывает 5-20 раз. При нажатии кнопки <kbd>Поиск</kbd> мышкой такого нет.

Как такого избежать? Можно ли средствами JS это реализовать?

На текстовое поле наложен jQuery обработчик:

```
var myobj = {

    txtSearch: $('#txtSearch'),
    btnSubmit: $('#btnSubmit'),

    init: function () {
        this.btnSubmit.on('click', this.action.bind(this));
        this.txtSearch.on('keyup', this.action.bind(this));
    },

    action: function (e) {
        //проверяем клик по кнопке или энтер
        if (e.keyCode !== 13 && e.type !== 'click') {
            return;
        }

        this.disableForm();
        //getAjax()
    },


    getAjax: function (code) {
        $.ajax({...})
            .done(function (r) {
                this.enableForm();
            }.bind(this));
    },

    disableForm: function () {
        this.btnSubmit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        this.txtSearch.off('keyup', this.action.bind(this));
    },

    enableForm: function () {
        this.btnSubmit.removeAttr('disabled');
        this.txtSearch.on('keyup', this.action.bind(this));
    },
};
```

Скриншот одного нажатия клавиши <kbd>Enter</kbd>, то есть, проблему видно налицо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Update**: нашел проблемку, при нажатии enter отключал форму `this.txtSearch.off('keyup', this.action.bind(this));`, а затем при загрузке результата включал её обратно `this.txtSearch.on('keyup', this.action.bind(this));`

Я думал, что обработчик удаляется, а затем заново навешивается. На самом деле, обработчик не удаляется, а наоборот плодится в геометрической прогрессии.

Comment: причина ситуации: ваше отключение слушателя keyup через bind-ованный объект ничего не отключает, а следующее «включение» добавляет ещё один обработчик и за счет этого количество запросов к серверу при следующем клике увеличивается на 1

Comment: а, я ехал в метро и недочитал, что вы это сами поняли. проблема в том, что каждый новый .bind дает не один и тот же, а разные объекты, т.е. отписка не выполняется. исправили?

Comment: @nörbörnën ну пока сделал отключение/включение текстового поля через `this.txtSearch.prop("disabled", false);`

Comment: кстати, код, который ты показал сегодня, совсем не соответствует теме проблеме, описанной в вопросе и даже вводит в заблуждение :) глядя на код хочется посоветовать не отключать обработчики, не дизаблить форму, а просто вызывать ajax запрос через underscorejs.org/#throttle или underscorejs.org/#debounce. т.е. при получении события пользовательского ввода откладывать ajax-запрос на некий таймаут и если было получено ещё одно событие то убивать существующий таймер и создавать новый (по той же схеме работающий)

Comment: Я подобное исправлял через таймаут для поиска на фронте, чтобы при вводе каждого символа не начинать заново поиск. Т.е. заводим таймаут, на таймаут выполняется действие, таймаут активируется при вводе символов и сбрасывается при повторном: https://github.com/gil9red/js__played_games_parser/blob/b39c14e4ddc82e2f84d60935e60907bb4504e772/index.html#L841

Comment: @nörbörnën код подкорректировал.

Comment: @Jean-Claude да, так корректней. спасибо :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Начну объяснение с небольшого эксперимента, проверим, являются ли два значения - одинаковыми значениями (т.е. ссылаются ли они на одно и то же). Для сравнения воспользуемся методом [`Object.is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is):

```js
const q = {a: true};
const z = q;
z.b = false;

console.log( Object.is(q, q) );
console.log( Object.is(q, z) );
```

Видим, что `Object.is` возвращает `true`, т.е. по ссылке один и тот же объект.

Теперь поставим эксперимент с сущностями, которые ближе к вопросу:

```js
const fn = () => {};
const bindedFn1 = fn.bind(window);
const bindedFn2 = fn.bind(window);

console.log( Object.is(bindedFn1, bindedFn2) );
```

Видим, что `Object.is` возвращает `false`, т.е. при каждом вызове `bind` создаётся новый объект.

#### Что происходит в твоём коде

```js
$().ready(() => {

    class Search {
        constructor() {
            this.count = 0;
            this.txtSearch = $('#search');
            this.txtSearch.on('keyup', this.action.bind(this));
        }
        
        action(ev) {
            console.log(`call action ${++this.count}`);
            this.txtSearch.off('keyup', this.action.bind(this));
            this.txtSearch.on('keyup', this.action.bind(this));
        }
    }
    
    const example = new Search();

    $(document).on('keyup', () => console.log('------------------'));

});
```

```html
<html>
  <body >
    <input id="search" type="text"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

В логе видно, что при текстовом вводе в input, с каждым новым событием количество вызовов функции `action` увеличивается, видна "серия" вызовов.

Так происходит из-за того, что при отписке от события, `this.txtSearch.off('keyup', this.action.bind(this))`, ты передал **не тот же** обработчик, который был передан при подписке. Такой же, но не тот же. Ты передал другую функцию. При отписке [нужно было передавать именно ту функцию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8), которую ты передавал при подписке, именно её следует удалить.

А "серия" вызовов образуется потому, что при первом вызове `action` добавляется +1 обработчик. При втором вызове 2 обработчика и добавляется ещё +2. На третьем 4 обработчика и добавляется ещё +4. Лавина.

#### Как нужно исправить твой код

Не зная что за сущность твой `this`, я покажу как решить проблему в лоб - просто сохраню в `this` экземпляр функции, которая станет обработчиком события keyup, вот так: `this.handlerKeyUp = this.action.bind(this)`

<sub>хотя ещё можно отписаться вообще от всего `this.txtSearch.off('keyup')`, но обычно так делать не рекомендуют</sub>

```js
$().ready(() => {

    class Search {
        constructor() {
            this.count = 0;
            this.txtSearch = $('#search');
            
            this.handlerKeyUp = this.action.bind(this);
            this.txtSearch.on('keyup', this.handlerKeyUp);
        }
        
        action(ev) {
            console.log(`call action ${++this.count}`);
            this.txtSearch.off('keyup', this.handlerKeyUp);
            this.txtSearch.on('keyup', this.handlerKeyUp);
        }
    }
    
    const example = new Search();

    $(document).on('keyup', () => console.log('------------------'));

});
```

```html
<html>
  <body >
    <input id="search" type="text"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

<sub>в [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) можно задекорировать метод так, чтоб он был autobind, но я не помню как это сделать в js. можешь поискать, для расширения кругозора :)</sub>

---

UDP by [Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988)

В функцию [.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/) передаётся строка со списком отслеживаемых событий в которых, опционально, можно указать [namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/). Таким образом можно кастомизировать отписку от обработчика:

```js
$().ready(() => {

    class Search {
        constructor() {
            this.count = 0;
            this.txtSearch = $('#search');

            this.txtSearch.on('keyup.ns', this.action.bind(this));
        }
        
        action(ev) {
            console.log(`call action ${++this.count}`);
            this.txtSearch.off('keyup.ns');
            this.txtSearch.on('keyup.ns', this.action.bind(this));
        }
    }
    
    const example = new Search();

    $(document).on('keyup', () => console.log('------------------'));

});
```

```html
<html>
  <body >
    <input id="search" type="text"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: если надо, добавил код для понимания this

Comment: ну а что это меняет? объяснение я написал, вариант решения я написал. поставь в init `this.handlerKeyUp = this.action.bind(this)` и дальше по тексту

Comment: я понял, дописал для полноты картины.

Comment: Раз уж тут jQuery, то обработчик можно добавить с неймспейсом и отписаться от всего неймспейса. `this.txtSearch.on('keyup.smth', this.action.bind(this))` и потом `this.off('keyup.smth')` // cc @Jean-Claude

Comment: @Qwertiy дополнить ответ?

Comment: @nörbörnën, ну можно :)

Comment: @Qwertiy за неймспейсы в jq не знал. Получается этот вариант наиболее подходящий для минимизации изменения кода))

Comment: @Jean-Claude вставлю 5коп: имхо, в реальном кейсе, а не в абстрактном из вопроса, тебе  вообще не нужно блокировать обработчик keyup - пусть посетитель вводит столько, сколько ему вздумается, тебе нужно дросселировать ajax-запрос как я и gil9red написали в верхних комментариях

Comment: @nörbörnën я не знаком с underscorejs, а смысла в автопоиске с таймаутом не вижу, у меня поиск должен выполняться только про клавише enter при окончательном вводе искомого слова, у gil9red я так понял реализовано как в поисковой строке гугла, для моего проекта бесполезно искать "полуслова".